# smart contract rollup vs sovereign rollups?

Tags: rollups

I read here about smart contract and sovereign rollups: https://celestia.org/learn/sovereign-rollups/an-introduction/.
I am curious to know what are the pros, cons and differences between both types of rollups
which is more trusted and which is easy to build.
it will be better if you give some examples of rollups present there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main difference is how settlement is conducted. Specifically, contract rollup uses a contract as the settlement entity, whereas sovereign rollup uses a separate chain as the settlement entity. This difference results in several different scenarios:

In terms of settlement logic upgrades, contract rollup relies on contract upgrades, which can be controlled by a multi-signature address and must be either black or white. Sovereign rollup, on the other hand, relies on whether miners support the upgrade. Those who support it go to the new chain, while those who do not remain on the old chain, which is commonly referred to as a fork in the blockchain industry.
As for bridges, this will be briefly omitted, as the above is the main reason.